# Python - Convert 24 character human readable date format like 'Tue May 16 04:10:55 PDT 2017' to yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

I would like to convert a date string like `'Tue May 16 04:10:55 PDT 2017'` to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

How can I do this? Preferably using inbuilt Python2 functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `dateutil.parser` can parse the text into a datetime object:

```
import dateutil.parser

datestr = 'Tue May 16 04:10:55 PDT 2017'
print dateutil.parser.parse(datestr)
```

This will print

```
2017-05-16 04:10:55
```

To get this into `yyyy-mm-dd`, you can use the `strftime` method of a datetime object:

```
print dateutil.parser.parse(datestr).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This will print

```
2017-05-16
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [parsedatetime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime) to parse the string, and then use `datetime` to format it:

```
import parsedatetime
cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
parsed = cal.parseDT('Tue May 16 04:10:55 PDT 2017')
formatted = parsed[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik. Is there a way that I can use in-built Python 2 functions?

Comment: @activelearner; Unless this just happens to be an academic exercise in which using native functions is a requirement, I would seriously re-think that approach. The power of python is in its packages - otherwise it is just a nice language. Parsedatetime is a crazy powerful tool that, like others, can reduce what would otherwise be complicated code to 1-liners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the avearge in-built **datetime** package.

```
import datetime
datetime.today()
datetime.time()
```